# AWS Elastic Beanstalk running two environments at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a following problem:

We are using Beanstalk to deploy our application. 
We would like to do AB Testing with two versions of the system running simultaneously and having only small fraction of the traffic redirected (it can be 10% of the traffic or 1 server) to the new version before we verify some of the business metrics.

Something similar to rolling deploys but I would like manually decide when I want to switch fully to the new environment.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two environments and then create a single route53 alias pointing to the two environments. You can use weighted DNS records to send a fraction of traffic to your environment. You can gradually shift the weights to your new environment when ready.

How to create aliases to your beanstalk environment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Weighted Routing Policy in Route 53: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html